# how to assign fixed podition within a div to make it responsive?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi assigned a fixed position on a div embeded in another div. But I am not able to get it responsive across display size. I want the #fixed div to stay fixed on the right side of my page and keep same position across display sizes.

```
html form

<div id="main">
<div id="fixed"></div>
</div>

 css
 #main {
      position:relative;
      margin: 0 auto; 
      }

#fixed {
       position:fixed;
       left: 80%;
       top: 40%; 
   }
```

Comment: That's not really what fixed does -> http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly set a percentage width to the outer div, #main, you should be all set.

`#main {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You question is not very clear, but I'll try an answer...

If you want it to "keep the same position across display sizes", then you should not set relative sizes (%), but fixed sizes (in pixels).

If your CSS rule is `left: 80%`, your `div` will be moved from the left edge of the screen by the equivalent of 80% of the window's width. If the window is 500 px wide, then the area between your `div` and the left edge will be 400 px wide.

But if you always want the same position whatever the size of the user's display size, this would work :

```
#fixed {
   position:fixed;
   right: 20px; /* Or whatever position you want */
   top: 50px;
}
```

By the way, I suggest you change "left" to "right", because you seem to be trying to place your `div` near the right side of the page.